# click,mouseover and mouseout conflict with Draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to jquery. I wanted to make the tab-like look,which on click display a page in specific frame. I wanted the tabs to be draggable too. However as I brought the draggable feature,the mouse-over,mouse-out and click do not work. That is,once the element is dragged ,the element does not respond to mouseenter,mouseout and click. Please refer to the code and my apologies for missing out on posts addressing the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('li').mouseover(function() {  $(this).attr('class', 'tabTdColorChange'); }
).mouseleave(function() {

    if (!$(this).hasClass('myselected')) {
        $(this).attr('class', 'tabTdColorOriginal');
    }
});


    $('li').draggable({ connectToSortable: "#tabTable", containment: "parent"}).click(function () {
    var $li_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).addClass('myselected tabTdColorChange');
    $(this).siblings('.myselected').removeClass('myselected').addClass('tabTdColorOriginal');
    $('iframe[id*="' + $li_id + '"]').attr('class', 'contentframe');
    $('iframe:not([id*="' + $li_id + '"])').attr('class', 'contentframehide');
});
$(function() {
    $("#tabTable").sortable();

});

});
```

Comment: The problem is that, to drag an element you have to click on it first. so adding a click event to a draggable will not work. 
The first solution i can come up with : [add a handle](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle) that will be used to drag the element, then specify a different area on your draggable ment for the click event.

Comment: After I drag the element. The element (which got dragged) does not respond to click,mouse-over and mouse-out.

Comment: Yes, just like i told you. The reason for that is that when an element is draggable, it will not respond to click events. So my idea was to do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/LJEZj/18/
You basically divide your draggable in different areas, where one is responsible for draggable events and a different one responsible for the click events, all inside a single <li> element.